# Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Miscroservices issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, spring-cloud

I tried to create an application based on an Amigoscode video on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p485kUNpPvE&t=2432s) but I have errors most probably due to the version that I use. I can't figure out what to fix. Could you please help me? The error that I get is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/.../Customer$CustomerBuilder.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/.../Customer$CustomerBuilder.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:457) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
    at com.ioannispriovolos.customer.CustomerApplication.main(CustomerApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/.../Customer$CustomerBuilder.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>2.5.7</spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>
    <spring.boot.dependencies.version>2.5.7</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I was trying to create the application using the latest versions of SDK (openjdk-19), language level (17 - Sealed types, always-strict floating-point semantics) and on modules Language level (19 - No new language features). I am using the latest version of IntelliJ CE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community My issue was with the version of the dependencies that I used. I should have used 3.0.2 instead of 2.5.7 in the pom.xml at spring.boot.maven.plugin.version and spring.boot.dependencies.version.

Answer (score 0):

- Spring Boot 2.5.7 does not work with JDK19 (`...core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably d`
- furthermore your project is not even on the latest [2.5.X version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.14/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements). The 2.5.X lines works upto JDK18. The most recent version on 2.5.X line is 2.5.14.
- [Spring Boot 2.6.X](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.14/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements) will work up to JDK19
- [Spring Boot 2.7.X](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.8/reference/htmlsingle/) will work up to JDK19.
- The 2.5.X, 2.6.X line are end of life see for details: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support
- You should migrate to Spring Boot 3.0.2.